# Dynamic loading of CSS in Dojo/Dijit?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, amd

The tutorial ["Creating a custom widget"](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/recipes/custom_widget/) proposes a directory structure for a dijit widget, that includes 'css' directory. Everything else in the example is dymanicly loaded using AMD, but not CSS. The authors write:

> Now, with that in place, we just need to add the CSS to our head on
>   our page, and we have a nicer looking author list!

However, does Dojo/Dijit has any mechanism that doesn't required putting all possible CSS stuff in HTML HEAD or some aggregating CSS (imports)?

It is possible to simply add the section to the header, but it requires checking first, if it was already loaded, and probably waiting for CSS to load. Is there some build-in solution for making that things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://davidwalsh.name/amd-xstyle and https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle#amd-plugin-loader

A brief example of usage, straight from the docs:

```
define(["xstyle!./path/to/file.css"], function(){
    // module starts after css is loaded
});
```

There have been some issues in the past when combining this with Dojo builds.  However, it appears @kriszyp has now documented this stuff fairly well - https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle#building-with-amd-plugin

Comment: So it's about to place `require(['xstyle/css!path/to/stylesheet.css'], function(){})` in the code and everyghing is transparently done by xstyle module? 
You could include some usage sample in the answer, at best the answer should still be valid if the links stop to function.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ - is the above helpful?